# PHP gnupg 'import failed'

Tags: php, mamp, gnupg

I have been trying to use gnupg in PHP to encrypt a file that will be uploaded to an ftp folder.  I am currently running on a mac using MAMP and I believe gnupg is installed correctly.

I have a public key from the recipient of the file and when I try to import the key, either as a string literal or from a text file, I get the cryptic 'import failed' message from gnupg.

```
$gpg = new gnupg();
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION);
$gpg->import($key); //throws exception 'import failed'
```

Is there a better resource for reasons a key would fail to import?

Using GPG Suite, I can successfully import the key, so I believe the key is correct

Comment: I had the same error, running PHP-FPM with PHP 7 & nginx. After a restart of the php-fpm it did work again, very strange...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the program has read-write access rights to the pubring.gpg file.  On my Linux Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS this is located in my own ~/.gnupg directory.  If not there, you may want to check the GNUPGHOME env. var.