# PHP Gnupg doesn't work

Tags: php, gnupg

I tried my best to install GnuPG extension in PHP but it does not work.

I followed a lot of instruction but I have not been successful.

This is the code, and it always produces the error:

> import failed

```
$keyring = "/var/www/.gnupg/";
putenv("GNUPGHOME=$keyring");
$GnuPG = new gnupg();
$GnuPG->seterrormode(GNUPG_ERROR_WARNING);
$PublicData = "key text";
$PrivateData = "key text";

$PublicKey = $GnuPG->import($PublicData); -->error here

$PrivateKey = $GnuPG->import($PrivateData); --> error here

echo 'Public Key : ',$PublicKey['fingerprint'],' & Private Key :',$PrivateKey['fingerprint'];
```

1. I tried to set the **GNUPGHOME** where the apache home directory is located (`/var/www/.gnupg`) in the code, but it does not work.
2. I give the permissions (777) to the folder `/var/www` to Apache user (www-data) but it does not work.

> ```
> drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 27 17:38 .
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 Jun 27 16:56 ..
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  383 Jun 27 16:50 pubring.gpg
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  383 Jun 27 16:50 pubring.gpg~
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  600 Jun 27 16:50 random_seed
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  753 Jun 27 16:50 secring.gpg
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 1280 Jun 27 16:50 trustdb.gpg
> ```

3. Environement

   PHP 5.3.10

   Ubuntu 12.04

   GPGme Version   1.2.0

   GnuPG Extension Version 1.3.6

The same problem in this thread:

[PHP gnupg 'import failed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768968/php-gnupg-import-failed)

Answer (score 0):

The access rights on your pubring.gpg and secring.gpg files seems correct.  You may want to drop the execute (x) right as that's not needed.  Could it happen that the files are corrupt?  May also want to run the program under strace to see if it is indeed accessing those file.